# Ways of making a java program to notify me

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I have a bot program that constantly checks for some changes and when some change happens, it should notify me with a message. The bot runs on its own machine and the notification should happen on my other machine (using internet).

So far I've used `Skype4java`, where the bot sent me a skype message. But since recently, if the bot sends a message, its never getting delivered (the loading circle in skype on the message stays forever), typing and sending the message by hand works fine tho. Anyways, I tried fixing that but i guess that skype library isn't working anymore, so I need a new way of doing that. I don't mind using help from some other application like skype.

Comment: [You don't have to guess](https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api), it's dead. We use xmpp for that kind of function, or interface with hangouts directly.

Comment: the most open messaging seems to XMPP/ Jabber, but standard has a small defeat too, when Google Talk change strategy

Answer (score 1):

Why not just send an e-mail?
It's simple, reliable, and well supported by libraries such as [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) and [CommonsEmail](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/). Plus, SMTP (the email sending protocol) is not proprietary, so you won't run into the same issues that you now have with Skype.

Comment: I want to see the content of the message instantly and without clicking much